# How to calculate a/b in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get value for a/b, but I always get '0' for a/b.

Why do I get a/b=0 ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a,b;
  cout << "Give a and b" << endl;
  cin >> a >> b;
  double q=a/b;
  cout << "a/b=" << q;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input values are you using?

Comment: If I had to guess, you're running into integer division.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using 1 and 2

Comment: @Laurel but I used double for q, shouldn't that make difference?

Comment: @user40 no. `a/b` is executed first, and its result (which is an integer) is assigned (and converted to) `q` after that.

Comment: At least cast one operand to `double` to avoid integer division: `double q=a/(double)b;`

Comment: @user40 and `1/2` is `0.5` which is 0 as an `int`.

Comment: use type cast: `double q = (double)a / (double)b;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using integer arithmetic, so the division result will be an integer. A floating point value that is between 0 and 1 will get truncated to 0 when interpretted as an integer, before it is assigned to your `q` variable.  So either:

1. change your `a` and `b` variables to `double` instead of `int`
2. typecast `a` and/or `b` to `double` during the division.

Either way, you will then be performing floating-point division instead of integer division, so the result will be a floating-point value.

Answer (score 1):

Can do `double q=double(a)/b;` instead.